# Parsing array into individual strings from a table view - Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've been trying to parse an array and split it into separate strings. I have managed to successfully get this working by individually adding a fixed `objectAtIndex` when I set the strings.

Example:

```
 NSString *weightString = [[[results valueForKey:@"Endurance"] objectAtIndex:7]objectAtIndex:2];
```

However, when I try and set the strings in a tableView `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` using any `objectAtIndex` the string always returns null. I need to be able to click on the tableView row using `objectAtIndex:indexPath.row`. I can't work out where I am going wrong. Feel free to request more code or queries.

Query:

```
PFQuery *arrayQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Exercises"]; 
[arrayQuery selectKeys:@[@"Endurance"]];
[arrayQuery orderByAscending:@"ExerciseName"];
[arrayQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *results, NSError *error) {
if (!error) { self.arrayResults = [results valueForKey:@"Endurance"];
```

cellForRowAtIndexPath:

```
- (TableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"list";
TableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

UILabel *cellTitle;
cell.cellTitle.text = [[browseAllArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"ExerciseName"];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell = [[TableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    //Exercise Bar Label
    cellTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80, 20, 220, 60)];
    cellTitle.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"ethnocentric" size:14];
    cellTitle.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    cellTitle.numberOfLines = 2;
    cellTitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;

    cell.cellTitle.text = [[browseAllArray objectAtIndex: indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"ExerciseName"];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
cellTitle.text = [[browseAllArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectForKey:@"ExerciseName"];
return cell;
```

Comment: share cellForRowAtIndex method.

Comment: Show `result` and `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

Comment: My cellForRowAtIndexPath method contains only the code to design the cell. Im trying to parse information from my database which corresponds to the relevant cell. Do you still need it? If so I will send it.

Comment: Edit your question with your code, do not put it in comment where it's not formatted and harder to read.

Comment: @Larme updated the original post for you. Thanks for the quick response so far.

Comment: Could you print `self.arrayResults`?

Comment: @Larme I can in my query and it returns all the results. I can also se the strings up the same way in my query and they work correctly if I output each to a log. Its just when I try and put them in the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method where they return null.

Comment: Is `self.arrayResults` nil in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`? If that's the case, you are missing the asynchrone concept. You need to call `[myTableView reloadData];` after `self.arrayResults = [results valueForKey:@"Endurance"];`. Now you are talking about `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` does it work in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`?

Comment: Yes i've tried self.arrayResults it returns null in both methods. I also tried adding the a reload data below where you suggested in the query, however, it made no difference.
EDIT: The self.arrayResults is returning just a opening bracket now which is weird

Comment: You may need to do the `reloadData` in main thread. Also, you have `self.arrayResults` and `browseAllArray`.

Comment: @Larme I have added a reloadData in the main thread. Also that is for a seperate query which perfectly works which is just parsing a few strings to the same place I want these strings to go haha

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve my problem by changing the string in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method.

Instead of using:

```
 NSString *weightString = [[[results valueForKey:@"Endurance"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]objectAtIndex:2];
```

I used:

```
 NSString *weightString = [[arrayResults objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:2];
```

I decided to try and use the array instead of results string as it wouldn't let me pull the information from the string. I would recommend following @Larme 's steps above as they definitely sent me in the right direction.

If people are trying to follow my steps make sure you remove the valueForKey as this was throwing a fatal error.